# Map from area US codes to zip codes

Tags: dictionary, tableau-api

Does anyone have a map from US area codes to zip codes? I understand this isn't exactly a complicated question but I need it for heatmaps in Tableau. (trasnlating phone numbers to zip codes for geomapping (Tableau doesn't support area code heatmaps.)) Because, ahem, there are approx 43k zip codes in the US...

Comment: how are you going to handle the overlaps (some zip codes span area codes)?

Comment: right zip code will not provide as high 'resolution'

Comment: I am okay with multiple area codes having the same zip code value

Comment: Create a new table or in your datasource that maps these values. Then heatmap by whichever is recognized by heatmap

Comment: I know I guess I'll just build up the map as I use the area codes.